# If $lim \int f_n dx$ exists and $<\infty$, can we switch limit and integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

A common example that we cannot switch limit and integral is $$f_n=1_{[n,\infty]}$$$lim\int f_ndx=\infty$, while $\int \lim f_ndx=0$. Thus we have Dominated Convergence Theorem. In my knowledge, such examples all deal with some integral which equals infinity. Here is my quesiton, if $\lim \int f_ndx$ exists and $<\infty$, can we switch the limit and integral?

Comment: As pointed out, that is not true. However, the idea you might have in mind is monotone convergence. If you have a sequence of functions so that $\int f_n dx \le \int f_{n+1} dx$ and all the $f_n$ are positive, then you can interchange integral and limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f_n=1_{[n,n+1]}$. That $\int f_ndx=1$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n=0$ pointwise, thus $\int \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n=0$

Answer (score 0):

No. Take $f_n$ to be an indicator function of width $1/n$ and height $n$. Assume it is centered around 0. Then the limit of the integral is just 1 but the integral of the limit is 0.